# How to use custom analyzers in the TFS build?

Tags: c#, tfs, roslyn-code-analysis

The company I work for has started using custom code analyzers (these were developed in-house) and now they're being used as NuGet packages that company developers must add to their projects. So far so good, but I was asked to find a way to reuse these same analyzers in a TFS build.

One important detail is that they use VS as a build agent.

So, my questions are:

1. How can I reuse these custom analyzers so they're included in every TFS build?
2. How do I make these analyzers to fail the build?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What version TFS are they using?  Are they using XAML builds or the newer vNext build agents?

Comment: Server is Visual Studio Team Foundation Server 2015. I think they're using vNext build agents.

Comment: To answer the second part of your question, as long as something in the build process writes to StdErr, a vNext build will fail.  As far as the first question goes... could you elaborate on how the NuGet packages are invoked?  If the NuGet packages hook directly into the build process (perhaps by using a .targets file), then you shouldn't have to do anything extra.  But if you have to manually invoke some executable that the NuGet package contains, then you'll have to add additional build steps to do the same.

Comment: Re: 1st question, I think they use targets files because all a developer has to do to use those analyzers is to simply add them via NuGet on their solutions and they're automatically exposed as analyzers in VS. Re: 2nd question, so maybe a console app that analyzes a solution and outputs errors to stderr as a build step in TFS is the answer?

Comment: That should do it.  vNext also lets you capture those steps as **task groups** so that you can reuse them in other build definitions

Comment: Thank you. One more question: analyzers are usually developed as DiagnosticAnalyzer classes with their corresponding CodeFixProviders, but of course they depend on VS infrastructure to use them for analysis. Can I reuse those same DiagnosticAnalyzers on a standalone code analysis tool and if so, how?

Comment: That, I don't know

Comment: How your custom analyzers works?   Did you just create custom code analysis rules in Visual Studio? And want to integrate this during your TFS build pipeline?

Comment: As I understand, all developers add the analyzermanually to VS via a NuGet package.If you added the code analyzer assembly in each project under References/Analyzers your code analyzer will be used with all builds, the TFS build as well. Your code analyzer assembly has to be available on all machines that execute your build of course. Another benefit: no developer will be able to "forget" to install the code analyzer via NuGet. The build fails automatically when a diagnostic analyzer reports an error.